# Удалить словари из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, коллекции

Есть словарь:

```
sp = {'animals': [{'animal': 'tiger', 'n': 1, 'id': [3]}, {'animal': 'bear', 'n': 4, 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {'animal': 'hare', 'n': 1, 'id': [1]}], 
'birds': [{'bird': 'tit', 'n': 2, 'id': [3, 4]}, {'bird': 'sparrow', 'n': 1, 'id': [1]}, {'bird': 'woodpecker', 'n': 2, 'id': [1, 4]}], 
'fish': [{'fish': 'perch', 'n': 3, 'id': [1, 3, 4]}, {'fish': 'herring', 'n': 1, 'id': [4]}, {'fish': 'shark', 'n': 1, 'id': [2]}]}
```

Необходимо создать новый словарь, в котором будут находиться значения из старого словаря, в которых в поле 'id' более одного значения, то есть необходимо получить словарь вида:

```
sp_new = {'animals': [{'animal': 'bear', 'n': 4, 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}], 
'birds': [{'bird': 'tit', 'n': 2, 'id': [3, 4]}, {'bird': 'woodpecker', 'n': 2, 'id': [1, 4]}], 
'fish': [{'fish': 'perch', 'n': 3, 'id': [1, 3, 4]}]}
```

В качестве решения использую такой алгоритм:

```
for key, value in sp.items():
    for i in range(0, len(value)):
        if len(value[i]['id']) == 1:
            del value[i]
```

Но тут при удалении какого словаря сбивается итерация. Знаю, что можно использовать метод reversed в цикле, но хотелось бы понять, как решить данную проблему с использованием нового словаря

Comment: Не надо использовать reversed, надо просто идти с другого конца ``for i in range(len(value)-1,-1,-1):``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте

Входные данные:

```
sp = {
    'animals': [
        {'animal': 'tiger', 'n': 1, 'id': [3]},
        {'animal': 'bear', 'n': 4, 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
        {'animal': 'hare', 'n': 1, 'id': [1]}
    ],
    'birds': [
        {'bird': 'tit', 'n': 2, 'id': [3, 4]},
        {'bird': 'sparrow', 'n': 1, 'id': [1]},
        {'bird': 'woodpecker', 'n': 2, 'id': [1, 4]}
    ],
    'fish': [
        {'fish': 'perch', 'n': 3, 'id': [1, 3, 4]},
        {'fish': 'herring', 'n': 1, 'id': [4]},
        {'fish': 'shark', 'n': 1, 'id': [2]}
    ]
}
```

Создание нового словаря:

```
sp_new = dict()
for k, items in sp.items():
    sp_new[k] = [item for item in items if len(item['id']) > 1]
```

Через генератор:

```
sp_new = {
    k: [item for item in items if len(item['id']) > 1]
    for k, items in sp.items()
}
```

Проверка:

```
expected = {'animals': [{'animal': 'bear', 'n': 4, 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}],
'birds': [{'bird': 'tit', 'n': 2, 'id': [3, 4]}, {'bird': 'woodpecker', 'n': 2, 'id': [1, 4]}],
'fish': [{'fish': 'perch', 'n': 3, 'id': [1, 3, 4]}]}
assert sp_new == expected
```

Comment: спасибо! работает как надо теперь

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, пожалуйста :)